# Json to c# Objects in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, steam-web-api

I've been wanting to make my own dota 2 stats website/app. Basically, I'm using the steam API to gather all the essential data. Most of this data is stored in Json format.

I've been trying to deserialise the format so that I can have the data in a readable format. Ideally I want to turn it into objects and then put them into a data grid so I can present this data properly to the user.

Additionally, I am using the Portable Steam WebAPI Wrapper for C# and Newtonsoft packages.

```
Public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   SteamWebAPI.SetGlobalKey("MysteamKey");

    var r2 =  SteamWebAPI.Game().Dota2().IDOTA2().GetHeroes().GetResponseString(RequestFormat.JSON);

    var ds1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(r2);
    RootObject hero = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(r2);


    Response.Write("Display Hero Data.. </br></br>");
    Response.Write( hero.result.heroes );


    Response.Write(hero);


   }
}
```

Here is my Hero class: I basically used this website to come up with it - http://json2csharp.com/ Additionally, the Json file can be found here https://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetHeroes/v0001/?key=2D13D618DA712015812E970165632F02&language=en_us

```
public class Hero
{
public string name { get; set; }
public int id { get; set; }
public string localized_name { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
public List<Hero> heroes { get; set; }
public int status { get; set; }
public int count { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

Currently, this is what is displayed from my current code:

" Display Hero Data..

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Hero]RootObject "

It doesn't seem to display any of the data from the json file :/
I'm sure i'm missing something straighforward here, but I just can't put my finger on it :(

I really need some assistence here, If I can get this working, then I can start pulling all the other data I need. I'd appreciate any help whatsoever.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Write( hero.result.heroes );`

That is just going to write out the "string" version of heroes. Since it's an object, it's just giving you List's (or Object's!) .ToString() function (which displays System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Hero]RootObject)

You're going to need to iterate over the collection. I see that you're directly writing out to the response, which I would discourage, but, if you want to see these written out with it, you can use something like this:

```
foreach(var hero in hero.result.heroes)
{
    Response.Write(String.Format("<p>Name: {0}, ID: {1}</p>", hero.name, hero.id)
}
```

Since it looks like you're messing around with webforms, I suggest you take a look at some tutorials on how to use it (or mvc)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I'm only using the response.write temporarily until I can sort this out. Then I can output the results directly into a datagrid.

Comment: he already has a hero object, try foreach(var hero1 in hero.result.heroes)

Comment: I noticed that, and already made the change, The website loads, and that is where the server error comes. I think I need to make a few more changes to the code.. I take it that when var goes through the json array, or (parse's through) it makes each element into an object right? Do you think I will need another method? A public static async Task? I've seen this before in a similar context. I don't know what it does but i'll do some reading/watch some videos about it.

Comment: Two things: You've included your API key in the post, and I did some simple testing from a console application, and was able to enumerate the json in the link you posted with structure similar to what I showed in the answer.

Comment: well, I got home and decided to give it another crack, I thought I'd try in a console app, same thing, console would just close..Anyway, I decided to go back to the webform and try again, and it just start working! I couldn't quite believe it. I thought to myself earlier, that everything makes sense it should work. I still don't know why I was getting those errors - bizzare,, But Thank you very much willaien, I really appreciate your help. I'm going to read more about this stuff, so I can get a firm grasp of it and become a better programmer.